# Power BI SharePoint Access

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

I am somewhat new to SharePoint and PowerBI so I could be missing a simple concept.  My initial search is not finding a quick answer - I suspect I have the set-up wrong but not sure where.

I have copied the report:

[image]

and then loaded in SharePoint:

[image]

now my users are sending me these:

[image]

PBI report is published to my Workspace:

[image]

My SharePoint site has managed access to a group:

[image]

What am I missing here - does my Power BI report need to be published to a group workspace?

I can send users a link but that is not going to work long term.